# Running Pig script in multiple node

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have configured a Hadoop cluster with three Nodes. All nodes are working fine and connected.

I have uploaded 28 GB file in HDFS and executing Pig script for process that file. While I am executing Script. Its running in single node only.

Could you please give me advice and explain why it is running in single node only? Am I missing something in configuration?

I am using Hadoop 2.2.0 and Pig 0.12 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to set `parallel` in your script? You have three nodes so you can try to set up to `parallel 3`. It makes sense to use it with any of the following operators:

- group
- cogroup
- join
- limit
- order
- distinct

Example of the syntax: `group x by y parallel 3;`

What format is your file? Make sure it is splittable.

Also check that your cluster is working and set up correctly. For example check that task trackers (resp. NodeManager in YARN) are not failing, make sure that `slaves` and `master` files are set correctly on all nodes (`slaves` lists all the slave nodes, `master` lists the master).

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I have not used parallel operator. My file is comma seperated.

Comment: So an ordinary CSV *text* file?

Comment: Yes, I have exported it from MySQL and stored in HDFS. Before that I have convert it into Unix format.

Comment: Also check that your cluster is working and set up correctly. For example check that task trackers are not failing, make sure that `slaves` and `master` files are set correctly on all nodes.

Comment: I did JPS in master and salves: Master processes are 13540 ResourceManager
17422 JobHistoryServer
10180 Jps
5711 RunJar
12860 NameNode
5804 MRAppMaster
13070 DataNode
6594 YarnChild
13758 NodeManager
23489 RunJar
13333 SecondaryNameNode and for Slave 28541 Jps
11298 DataNode
11515 NodeManager

Comment: that looks ok but the processes still could be failing, you should check the logs.

Comment: Last job was failed due to some reason. My job is running in single node, I have not applied your solution in scrip yet. Because My script is still running. Once it is finishes I will try parallel option. Can I use this option in script "set default_parallel 10;" ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that but anything more than 3 doesn't make sense on a 3-node cluster.